# Disable the Config field after entering data

Tags: magento2, configuration, system.xml

I am trying to disable the text field in the configuration field once admin has entered the data. I know it can be done via `<frontend_model>` but in that case the field gets disabled as soon as the page loads.

frontend_model class:

```
protected function _getElementHtml(AbstractElement $element): string
    {
        $element->setData('readonly', 1);
        return $element->getElementHtml();
    }
```

So, how can I disable it after the admin has entered value and saves configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one :

```
public function _getElementHtml(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element
    ) {
        /**
         * Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
         */
        $value = $this->scopeConfigManager->getValue('section_id/group_id/field_id');
        if (!empty($value)) {
            $element->setData('readonly', true);
        }
        return parent::_getElementHtml($element);
    }
```

In this way we can disable it after the admin has entered value and saves configuration.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to make the system configuration field read-only by setting filed value from app/etc/config.php

For example, is an example of how to set the title of the "Check / Money Order" payment method from the config.php

```
//app/etc/config.php    
return [
        'modules' => [
            .... // your native/default magento code here
        ],
        'system' => [
            'default' => [
                'payment' => [
                    'checkmo' => [
                        'title' => 'Check / Money order'
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

This is how you can set the value of each configuration value and this is can not be editable from the admin.